# Quickly creating a sparse array

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

The motivation for my question is that I'm creating very large, very sparse symmetric matrices and finding the largest eigenvalue.  (Think **upwards** of $10^5\times 10^5$ size matrices, with at most $10^2$ nonzero entries on each row.  However, to give a workable example, below I'll use $10^4\times 10^4$ size matrices, with $30$ nonzero entries.)  The entries are mostly independent of one another, although there is some time savings in working with one row at a time.  (In the example below, I model this type of behavior by having the constant $c$ in the computation depend only on the row index.  In the actual work I do, the dependence isn't quite that simple.)  By symmetry, we may focus on the part of the matrix above the main diagonal.  (For simplicity, I'm assuming the main diagonal is zero in the example below.)

So, to give a toy example consider the following code:

```
M = Table[0.0, {i, 1, 10000}, {j, 1, 10000}];
Do[
   c = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
   PossibleColumns = RandomSample[Range[i + 1, 10000], Min[10000 - i - 1, 30]];
   Do[
      M[[PossibleColumns[[j]], i]] = c/RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
      M[[i, PossibleColumns[[j]]]] = c/RandomInteger[{1, 10}],
   {j, 1, Length[PossibleColumns]}
   ],
{i, 1, 9999}
];
Eigenvalues[M, 1];
```

The creation of the large array takes a couple seconds, and seems to fill up about 1 GB of RAM.  (For the larger matrices I want to build, I quickly run out of RAM.)  It takes about 3 seconds to update the nonzero entries in the matrix $M$.  Finally, the eigenvalue function takes about 3 minutes.

If I replace the top line with the new line

```
M = SparseArray[{}, {10000, 10000}, 0.0];
```

and rerun the entire code, then there are no RAM problems (even for much, much larger matrices).  The eigenvalue step is almost instantaneous.  However, the updating takes over an hour!  I was very surprised that the updating takes so long, so I made the following intermediate version, which rather than updating each entry of $M$ independently, it updates each row of $M$ once.

```
M = SparseArray[{}, {10000, 10000}, 0.0];
Do[
   c = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
   jRow = SparseArray[{}, {10000}, 0.0];
   PossibleColumns = RandomSample[Range[i + 1, 10000], Min[10000 - i - 1, 30]];
   Do[
      jRow[[PossibleColumns[[j]]]] = c/RandomInteger[{1, 10}],
   {j, 1, Length[PossibleColumns]}
   ];
   M[[i]] = jRow,
{i, 1, 9999}
];
M = M + Transpose[M];
Eigenvalues[M, 1];
```

This has the RAM savings, and the eigenvalue savings, and finishes the updating of $M$ in a little over 4.5 minutes.

My question is this:  Is there a way to keep (most of) the RAM savings of using a sparse array, along with the time saving in the eigenvalue computation, but also reduce the time used in updating $M$ down to the timing in the first example (which only used 3 seconds)?

Comment: If you can express the values of the non-zero terms as a function of the position indices, you should be able to construct the `SparseArray` from the ground up, by giving a list of rules, or by using patterns and conditions. That should be MUCH better than modifying them element-wise.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, I have a function $f(i,j)$ that gives the value of the matrix in the $(i,j)$ coordinate.  Moreover, I have a function $g(i)$ that gives me a list of those $j$ such that the $(i,j)$ entry is nonzero.  (In the toy example above, you would replace "PossibleColumns" by $g(i)$, and you would replace "c/RandomInteger[{1,10}]" with $f(i,j)$.)  I don't know how to turn that into a faster population of the sparse array though; any help with the syntax would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share those functions, perhaps expressed both in plain language, and in Mathematica code? Just in case one of the two is more readable than the other.

Comment: Changing elements of sparse arrays is slow because the whole array must be re-built after each change. *Do not assign elements in a loop!!* Instead, generate a list like `{i,j} -> value` first, then built the sparse array in a single step.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the first documented usage for [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

[image]

So what you want to do is collect all of the rules `{i,j}->val` *before* passing them to `SparseArray`.  There is already a built-in method for efficiently collecting a set of rules with no duplicate keys, namely [`AssociateTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociateTo.html).

So with a slight modification of the OP's code:

```
data=<||>;
Do[
   c = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
   PossibleColumns = RandomSample[Range[i + 1, 10000], Min[10000 - i - 1, 30]];
   Do[
      AssociateTo[data, {PossibleColumns[[j]],i} -> c/RandomInteger[{1, 10}]];
      AssociateTo[data, {i,PossibleColumns[[j]]} -> c/RandomInteger[{1, 10}]];
      ,
   {j, 1, Length[PossibleColumns]}
   ],
{i, 1, 9999}
];
```

The above runs in ~3.5 seconds on my machine, and constructing the `SparseArray` is very fast as well:

```
SparseArray[Normal[data]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: This is both clean and very fast.  I didn't realize that "AssociateTo" for association lists was so much faster than "AppendTo" for normal lists.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can help!

Answer (score 11):

Let's assume we are given the following data:

```
n = 100000;
k = 100;

g[i_] := RandomSample[i + 1 ;; n, Min[n - i - 1, k]];
f[i_, jlist_] := RandomReal[{1, 10}, Length[jlist]];

rowcolumnindices = g /@ Range[1, n - 1];
rowlengths = Length /@ rowcolumnindices;
rowvalues = MapIndexed[
   {jlist, i} \[Function] f[i[[1]], jlist], 
   rowcolumnindices
   ];
```

Probably the most efficient way to populate the sparse array with this data is by preparing the [CRS data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) by hand and to use the following undocumented constructor:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[
 orderings = Ordering /@ rowcolumnindices;
 columnindices = Partition[Join @@ MapThread[Part, {rowcolumnindices, orderings}], 1];
 rowpointers = Accumulate[Join[{0}, Length /@ rowcolumnindices, {0}]];
 values = Join @@ MapThread[Part, {rowvalues, orderings}];
 M = # + Transpose[#] &[
   SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {n, n}, 0., {1, {rowpointers, columnindices}, values}}
   ];
 ]
```

> 1.53083

I used machine real values here (not rational numbers) because they will be processed much faster, in particular in `Eigenvalues`.

The CRS format assumes that the column indices for each row are in ascending order. This is why we have to sort the column indices *and* the corresponding values first (this explains the extra fuzz around `orderings`).

Comment: In the toy example I gave above, the entries are chosen randomly.  In the actual computation I care about the entries are determined by the coordinates.  I made the toy example different in this way for two reasons: (1) the deterministic function is very complicated, and (2) I wanted to easily create a large matrix to help illustrate the situation.  So, I'm having trouble converting your beautiful ideas to my situation, because "rowvalues" is not so easily created.  My problem really boils down to trying to put all that data in a list quickly, as you have done with rowvalues.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that you can compute the values of each row before the actual matrix is constructed. I tried to address the functions `f` and `g` in my recent edit. The only difference of my function `f` to yours is that it expects a whole list of `j`s  as a second argument so that it creates all values of a row at once. Does this help?

Comment: This looks great!  I'm still trying to understand it all.  I'll let you know soon if I have any further questions.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Just in case you haven't noticed it, yet: I used the sizes of `n = 100000` and `k = 100` as you indicated for your goal (instead of `n = 10000` and `k = 30`). By direct comparison, my approach is more than 20 times faster than collecting the array rules with `AssociateTo` and applying `SparseArray` on these rules. Might be relevant for your application...

Comment: I'll give your method another look.  (I did code it up and the other was faster [because of the nature of how I was computing my functions], but I might have done it in a bad way.)

Comment: I think part of the speedup I'm noticing with the other code is that it is computationally expensive to compute your "rowcolumnindices" (and collect those together).  Moreover, it is faster to compute f using some auxiliary information collected when computing g.  So, in some sense, I think I really need that "Do" command over the index i, as in the other answer.  If you could speed it up with that part still present it would be helpful.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Without more info on f and g, it is hard to tell how to speed them up. Probably with `Compile`.